# How to keep original rotate page in itextSharp (dll)

Tags: excel, pdf, rotation, pdf-generation, itext

i would like create the project, reading from Excel and write on pdf and print this pdf. 
From Excel file (from cell) read directory where is original pdf on computer or server, and next cell have info what write on the top in second pdf.

And problem is here, original pdf is horizontal, landscape, rotate and my program create copy from original pdf and write info from excel on the top on copy pdf file. But pdf which is landscape is rotate for 270 deegres. This is no OK. For portrait rotation working program OK, copy OK and write on the top of the copy is OK. 
Where is my problem in my code.

Code:

```
public int urediPDF(string inTekst)
{
    if (inTekst != "0")
    {
        string pisava_arialBD = @"..\debug\arial.ttf";
        string oldFile = null;
        string inText = null;
        string indeks = null;
        //razbitje stringa
        string[] vhod = inTekst.Split('#');
        oldFile = vhod[0];
        inText = vhod[1];
        indeks = vhod[2];

        string newFile = @"c:\da\2";

        //odpre bralnik pdf
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);                
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(reader.NumberOfPages);
        Document document = new Document(size);

        //odpre zapisovalnik pdf                
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile + "-" + indeks + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        //document.Open();
        document.OpenDocument();
        label2.Text = ("Status: " + reader.GetPageRotation(reader.NumberOfPages).ToString());

        //določi sejo ustvarjanje pdf
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

        //izbira pisave oblike
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(pisava_arialBD, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);

        //pisanje teksta v pdf
        cb.BeginText();
        string text = inText;

        //izbira koordinat za zapis pravilnega teksta v pdf (720 stopinj roatacija (ležeče) in 90 stopinj (pokončno))
        if (reader.GetPageRotation(1) == 720)               //ležeča postavitev
        {
            cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 10, 450, 0);
            cb.EndText();
        }
        else                                              //pokončna postavitev
        {
            cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text + " - pokončen", 10, 750, 0);
            cb.EndText();
        }


        // create the new page and add it to the pdf
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, reader.NumberOfPages);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

        // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "Status: Končano zapisovanje";
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Picture fake pdf:

[image: Fake PDF]

Comment: You unfortunately found sample code that should not be used like that. If you want to take a PDF and stamp additions on it, base your code on the [Webified iTextSharp Example](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx) [StampText.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=StampText) explained in [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/index.php). Instead of `PdfWriter`it uses `PdfStamper` which uses the source pages as they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained many times before ([ITextSharp include all pages from the input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218126/itextsharp-include-all-pages-from-the-input-file/15218677#15218677), [Itext pdf Merge : Document overflow outside pdf (Text truncated) page and not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770942/itext-pdf-merge-document-overflow-outside-pdf-text-truncated-page-and-not-di/14771651#14771651), and so on), you should read [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book) (you can find the C# version of the examples [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06)).

You are using a combination of `Document`, `PdfWriter` and `PdfImportedPage` to split a PDF. Please tell me who made you do it this way, so that I can curse the person who inspired you (because I've answered this question hundreds of times before, and I'm getting tired of repeating myself). These classes aren't a good choice for that job:

- you lose all interactivity,
- you need to rotate the content yourself if the page is in landscape,
- you need to take the original page size into account,
- ...

Your problem is similar to this one [itextsharp: unexpected elements on copied pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309651/itextsharp-unexpected-elements-on-copied-pages). Is there any reason why you didn't read the documentation? If you say: *"I didn't have the time"*, please believe me if I say that I have almost 20 years of experience as a developer, and I've never seen "reading documentation" as a waste of time.

Long story short: read the documentation, replace `PdfWriter` with `PdfCopy`, replace `AddTemplate()` with `AddPage()`.

Comment: Would you please fix the broken link to sourceforge (the tinyurl link)?